# Disable autologin in TTY consoles in Kali Linux live system (with persistence)

Tags: linux, login, kali-linux, tty

I have kali live 2023.4 installed on my usb stick (with persistence partition) and I want to disable autologin in TTY consoles. When I open TTY on my computer, it automatically logins as kali. On my virtual machine (same kali linux version but not live) TTY console asks login and password when firstly opened:
[image: see image]
How can I achieve the same result on my live system?

Comment: "live" is live, not exactly an installation but media used to install. A desktop Linux actually installed in an USB drive is no different than one installed in an internal drive. You can't change the settings in a live image unless you're able to modify the ISO and, if you're asking here, then clearly you aren't.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have persistence partition configured so I can save settings.

Comment: @t1m013y "persistence" is only for user data and files (such as drivers) to be *added* to the system, it does not necessarily allow you to change files that already exist or the way the live USB works. You should install it properly if you need to configure the basic system.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1030047/how-do-i-disable-automatic-login-in-a-debian-live-standard-image

Comment: @ChanganAuto There is no `/etc/live/` directory.

Comment: Exactly. Please re-read the previous comments.

Comment: @Mokubai I have properly installed and configured persistence partition that lets me edit system files (I already edited some conf files, and changes saved after reboot)

Comment: The time you "wasted" already would have been better spent doing an actual installation, personal opinion. Also keep in mind Kali is for experts only doing one specific task (or a specific set of correlated tasks) only.

Comment: The question is not how to do this on a live system, I just need to know which configuration files I need to change to disable default login in TTY.

Comment: @t1m013y changes in a persistent partition may not be seen until relatively late in the boot sequence as the drive is mounted *after* configuration setup from the live system. You may have to edit the files in the squashfs system used by the live system, or whatever system the live image uses. You may well end up with `/etc` amd other system directories being remounted in your persistent partition, but those will only be available *after* that drive is mounted, probably just before the windows manager starts, before that point you will use the files provided by the live system.

Answer (score 1):

The tty login prompt is initially shown by `agetty`, which on systemd-based distributions is started through `getty@<tty>.service` (earlier, it used to be started through /etc/inittab).

Almost always, tty auto-login is implemented by adding certain options to the `agetty` command-line for those ttys. Look inside the systemd service to check if that is the case.

Comment: I tried to replace `ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --noclear - $TERM` with `ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear - $TERM` in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service` but after reboot it auto-logged in again

Comment: Did you edit the correct file? You shouldn't generally need to edit anything in /usr/lib. What does `systemctl cat getty@tty1` show?

Comment: I found something https://imgur.com/suRLok9.png

Comment: Edited these files but changes reverted after reboot

Comment: Those look like they are dynamically generated (as is everything in /run). Start at `man systemd.generator`, there's apparently a Kali-specific config generator among those. Is this a full installation or is it a "live usb" kind of system?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Definitely a "live" system and that's the problem. The OP has been suggested a couple of times to do an actual installation but here we are still... It would've taken less than 30 min even with an old and slow USB stick but some people are really stubborn.

Comment: @u1686_grawity It's live system with persistence partition

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I think it is suitable only for live system.

I added lines

```
LIVE_CONFIG_NOAUTOLOGIN=true
export LIVE_CONFIG_NOAUTOLOGIN
```

to `/lib/live/init-config.sh`

(optional) Also I disabled printing hostname in login prompt by adding line `LOGIN_PLAIN_PROMPT yes` in the file `/etc/login.defs`.